# SSRS Space Issue in Parameter Value

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2008-r2

I am facing some issues with parameter in SSRS reports that when my Multi value parameter contains the space in between then I get the syntax error

If i choose any other parameter value which do not contains the space then it works well. I am using SSAS cube as a data source

```
 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[PV] AS @Percentile
Member [Measures].[CntCT] as Count(NonEmpty(STRTOSET(@State) * [Tb Main].[UID].[UID].ALLMEMBERS,[Measures].[CPT1] ))
Member [Measures].[PVInt20] as  Int(((([Measures].[CntCT] - 1)* [Measures].[PV])/100) - 1)

Member [Measures].[PVC] as 
([Measures].[CPT1],Order(NonEmpty(STRTOSET(@State)*[Tb Main].[UID].[UID].ALLMEMBERS ,
[Measures].[CPT1]), [Measures].[CPT1],BASC).Item([Measures].[PVInt20]))

Select [Measures].[PVC] on columns, STRTOSET(@State) on rows from [POC 1];
```

Query works in query designer with both parameter and entire unique name i.e `[Tb Main].[State Name].&[Wash DC]`

Comment: What is the query that populates the state parameter drop down and which field is used for the parameter value? Hopefully you used the MDX unique name as the parameter value

Comment: State parameter values are setting from another data set below is the data set query: SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[CPT1] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Tb Main].[State Name].[State Name].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [POC 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the state parameter query to:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[ParamValue] as [Tb Main].[State Name].CurrentMember.UniqueName
SELECT { [Measures].[ParamValue] } ON COLUMNS, 
NonEmpty ([Tb Main].[State Name].[State Name].ALLMEMBERS, [Measures].[CPT1] ) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM [POC 1]
```

Use the ParamValue column as the value property of the state parameter. Then your query downstream should work even when there are spaces.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but i need more help that if i use [Measures].[ParamValue] as available values for the parameter data set then in drop down i am getting values like  [Tb Main].[State Name].&[Wash DC] which is not good to show user.

Comment: Thanks Greg i get it now after setting the value field to Param value and label to state name sorry i don't understand it in one go but now i got that thanks for your effort.